# Different style on input with text than on input without text

Tags: css

Is it possible to have a different style on a text input when there is text in the input box than when there is no text in the input box?

I know you can add a class on blur with JavaScript if the input has text, but is there a css-only solution?

Comment: Not possible using pure CSS however you can use focus selector as mentioned in answer below but this will not work when element is out of focus.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately there is no CSS-only solution.

You would have to use JavaScript to test if the input's value's length is greater than 0 and if so either apply a class or change the style.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, there is no CSS solution.

The closest you could come would be to use the `:focus` pseudo-class. It would change styles if the cursor is in the text box. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mjJpb/) is an example